# Device running error

Tags: linux, ubuntu

[image][image]
 I am tried to update Ubuntu and after that when I restart it I saw this message :

> The system is running in low-graphics mode

What can I do to fix that?

Comment: Double-posted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/424574/246819